# SQL: count values in one table based on WHERE from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, where-clause

I am not sure, why this is not working.

I have two simple tables:

```
Orders
OrderTypeID EmployeeID   Completion_needed
10308       72             15%
10309       73             20%
10310       74             30%

Customers
Customer ID   OrderTypeID   OrderDate    Order_completed
    1          10308       2015-09-18          5%
    2          10309       2015-09-19          30%
    3          10310       2017-09-20          25%
    4          10308       2015-09-18          17%
    2          10308       2015-09-19          20%
    3          10309       2017-09-20          7%
```

I want to calculate how many customers have non completed orders, where Order_completed in the Customers table is less than Completion_needed in the Orders table (please not that a customer can have more than one order type).

This is my query, but I get the wrong result:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.CustomerID) as count_employees
FROM Orders od
JOIN Customers c
ON od.OrderTypeID = c.OrderTypeID
WHERE od.Completion_needed > c.Order_completed
```

I get 1; but I should get the count of 2.

Comment: what do you mean by non-completed order here?

Comment: Are those the real tables? I don't see a CustomerID in the first so how does the join work?

Comment: @dman2306 sorry,I miss typed when I simplified it, it should be joined on OrderTypeID

Comment: @vkp the percentage of order_completed in the customers table being less than the percentage needed as noted in the orders table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you get "1" from your query.  I see it producing "3".  So, I think what you need is `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustomerId)
  FROM Orders od JOIN
       Customers c
       ON od.OrderTypeID = c.OrderTypeID
  WHERE c.Order_completed < od.Completion_needed;
```

Comment: thank you - do I not need an order by, if I do a group by or do I need a group by if I do an order by?

Comment: @jeangelj . . . The `GROUP BY` was left in there by mistake.